# Error in NavigationView methods after updating gradle dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, gradle-dependencies

I have this (previously) functioning code:

```
    if (navigationView.getHeaderCount() > 0) {
        navigationView.removeHeaderView(navigationView.getHeaderView(0));
    }
```

After updating gradle dependencies, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Which is strange because I can see [there's nothing on the documentation stating it was removed or something](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getHeaderCount()).

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App module gradle (relevant parts only):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1'
    compile 'com.greysonparrelli.permiso:permiso:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Edit

After cleaning/rebuilding/restarting, I commented those two lines, and the app crashes:

```
05-28 22:02:43.634 12434-12434/com.example.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter>
05-28 22:02:43.637 12434-12434/com.example.myapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
05-28 22:02:43.638 12434-12434/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 12434
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.ui.maintabscreen.MainTabbedActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.myapp.ui.maintabscreen.MainTabbedActivity.onCreate(MainTabbedActivity.java:74)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at com.example.myapp.ui.maintabscreen.MainTabbedActivity.onCreate(MainTabbedActivity.java:74) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at com.example.myapp.ui.maintabscreen.MainTabbedActivity.onCreate(MainTabbedActivity.java:74) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:82)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at com.example.myapp.ui.maintabscreen.MainTabbedActivity.onCreate(MainTabbedActivity.java:74) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Note that this line is logged like 20 times before the crash:

```
05-28 22:02:43.634 12434-12434/com.example.myapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
```

Comment: Did you try to clean and build the project?

Comment: clean and rebuild your project....also delete the cache of android studio

Comment: Did clean and rebuild, same error :/

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the [SDK Build Tools Releases](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html#notes), I saw that the version I'm using (23.3.0) was released on March 2016.

The Support Library version I was using (23.1.0) was [from October 2015](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

So I changed my Support Library version to the one released on May 2016 (23.4.0) and my app compiled and ran correctly:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```